# Is allocating a portion of tokens to the dapp creator after a crowdsale a bad business move?

Tags: dapps

Will this lessen the integrity of the dapp?  Will people trust the company less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're outside the dapp/crowdsale company and allocate tokens to the creator I don't see why this would negatively impact the integrity of the company.

If you're inside the dapp/crowdsale company and allocate tokens to yourself/your company as the creator I also don't see why this would hurt the integrity as long as you are transparent about how the tokens are being used. It is common, just as traditional companies, for the creator/company to maintain much of the equity in order to further develop the system.